# Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo.config.DemoAppConfig

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, javabeans

I had problems with context initialization. I don't use xml-configuration files. I've wanted to make spring configuration with no xml, but error appears. Please help to solve.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo.config.DemoAppConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver]: Factory method 'viewResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:625)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1287)
```

My DemoAppConfig

```
package com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo")
public class DemoAppConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        
        return viewResolver();
    }
    
}
```

my WebInit

```
public class MySpringMvcDisptacherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {DemoAppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

I know my problem is in DemoAppConfig but i am simply not able to find it. It has to be with Resolver.
But i am not getting the result i want.

Comment: You are returning `viewResolver()` which is calling itself again. You want to return `viewResolver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewResolver()` method invokes itself. This will never end, until the stack (which keeps track of method invocations) runs out of capacity - the "stack overflows".

See [the answer to "What is a StackOverflowError?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/214758/1523342) for an excellent in-depth explanation.

Instead of invoking `viewResolver()` again, I think you want to return the local variable `viewResolver` (take care, no brackets here).

Answer (score 0):

Try to return
return viewResolver;
instead of
return viewResolver();

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo")
public class DemoAppConfig {

    // define a bean for ViewResolver

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        
        return viewResolver;
    }
    
}
```